# Random space issue in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I've developed this site but I can't for the life of me figure out where the whitespace is coming from in firefox.

The site is here http://www.dance-etc.co.uk/ and its on the homepage under the top menu. In chrome/safari and IE the slider buts up nicely.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use the dom inspector (right-click white space, select 'Q'). it'll help track down stuff like this.

Comment: Thanks for that, I couldn't see anything in firebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

div.row: styles.css, line 243

It's the 30 px of bottom margin. Change it to 0 and it works fine in Chrome and FF.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the other dude just got there quicker

Comment: No he didn't. Check the time stamps.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has to do with the margin of the `.row`. Currently it has `margin: 0px 0px 30px;`, this makes the 30 px shift.